# How to change the border-radius in the below image? Mantra Theme

Tags: 18.04, themes

How to change the border-radius in the below image?

Using Mantra Theme, Ubuntu 18.04

[image]

Here is the link to the Theme: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tX3e8uqo_dOegklSvhg9ZQ3b9virBWD/view?usp=sharing

Update 1:

It looks like this now

[image]

Update 2 :

The button is too grey. Can we make it lighter ?

[image]

Comment: the theme Materia you mentioned is GTK or Shell theme??

Comment: Looks like it is the gnome-shell.css we need to change. Changed now :) Thanks.

Comment: @PRATAP , I have another issue. Added as an update to the original post. Please check.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: css file is here  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/10dbagb4qAsrhR2aFhS-Cw0hONz2rPrzK/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Workaround***

I have chosen `48px` as the `border-radius` for the below workaround. you may change this value according to your needs.

Edit the file `..../themes/Mantra/gtk-3.22/gtk.css`

[image]

look for the below content:

```
/***********
 * Dialogs *
 ***********/
messagedialog.background {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

messagedialog .titlebar {
  min-height: 24px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

messagedialog .titlebar:backdrop {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

messagedialog.csd.background {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0;
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

and edit it like below:

```
/***********
 * Dialogs *
 ***********/
messagedialog.background {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
border-radius: 0 0 48px 48px;
}

messagedialog .titlebar, messagedialog.csd .titlebar {
  min-height: 48px;
  border-style: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
border-radius: 48px 48px 0 0;
}

messagedialog .titlebar:backdrop {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 0;
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}

messagedialog.csd .dialog-action-area button:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

Then go to line number around 3739 and find below content:

```
messagedialog.csd decoration {
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Change 2px to 48px as I have chosen this size as border-radius.. you have to put as per your liking.

[image: le]

Comment: It looked different. There was no line 3730 in my file. I ends at 3300~ :( I have updated the original post. The popup is still square.

Comment: Herer https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXbWItGvwqgvaZzuUd3krB47_5tulNpp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Full folder is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/11tX3e8uqo_dOegklSvhg9ZQ3b9virBWD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated OP, please check.

Comment: I deleted the existing code and replaced with the one you suggested. Now it is back to where we started. Square box and black header gone. :(

Comment: I was being too careful. Deleted and copy pasted what you have given. Now it works like a charm. Thank you very much. I have more issue to deal with. The button is too grey. Shall I add it here, or start a new question ?

Comment: Updated the original post. Please check.

Comment: the pic is from the same edited theme for Mantra? and the folder you provided me?

Comment: Yes. I was using the " export " option from GIMP.

Comment: It's ok. I will try to see the " button " code. Thanks for trying :) PS : If you ever need some graphics help, let me know